# angular-translate: how to reset translation table dynamically in $translationProvider?

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, ionic-framework, angular-translate

I am using angular-translate to display different languages in my application, but I get an error when I try to refresh the translation data after a successful login or via other web service calls.

Note: I successfully invoke `$translateProvider.useLoader` in my "app.config" to set the default translation data.  But I need to reset that data dynamically in the app after any web service call as the language data varies by logged-in user's organization (or may change at any time).

This is the code I tried which gives me a `$translateProvider` unreferenced error:

```
var ctrl = angular.module('app.ctrls', ['pascalprecht.translate']);

ctrl.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$translate' 
                             ,'$translateProvider'   // << error!
                   , function( $translate  
                             , $translateProvider ) {
    ...
    // call web service to refresh "translations" in $translateProvider
}]);
```

FYI, the application is a mobile app using the Ionic framework which is based on angularjs.

Comment: My workaround right now is to store any recently downloaded LanguageData file into local storage -- and then read that in if it's available whenever the config phase runs again.  The problem with this workaround is that the user needs to kill or exit the app from running on their mobile phone in order for the config phase to be executed again.  Ideally I would like the new data to take effect immediately (or at least without having to kill the app).

Comment: SOLVED - as per JB Nizet's answer I am calling $translate.refresh() whenever a web service call returns an indicator to say that the language data has changed.  This invokes the $translateProvider.useLoader() that I had setup in my "app.config", which is a satisfactory solution.  Originally I was trying to set the data based on a payload from *any* web service call (if there was one), but this keeps things clean and simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providers can only be used during the configuration phase. Once the application runs, only services (created by the providers) are available.

But the `$translate` service has a [`refresh()`](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.$translate#methods_refresh) method.

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet, I figured as much.   So how do I load my newly downloaded languageData JSON file into the $translate before I apply refresh()?

Comment: Have you read the documentation of refresh()? What does it say? It says that it uses a loader to load the new translation tables. Loaders are described her: https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/12_asynchronous-loading and custom loaders (if you need them) here: https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/13_custom-loaders

Comment: You are absolutely right JB Nizet!  I simply added a call to "$translate.refresh()" at the appropriate moment after any web service call (such as after login, or when the service returns a flag indicating a new language refresh is required).  I had read that documentation but it seemed to be more about partial loading of data and for multiple languages.  After a long day, I missed the woods for the trees.